# Iterators and iterables

Tags: python, loops, iterable

I was reading a book about python (beginning python, from novice to prefessional, 3rd edition) and noticed the following sentence which has confused me considering that I am a beginner

"in many cases you would put the **iter** method in another object which you would use in the for loop, that would then return your iterator" page 179

I read every sources that I could find and I am still confused because in all of them we put the **iter** in one class, make objects from it and then that object gets used in for loop and we never put it in another class

I would be grateful if you correct me if i am wrong and give me a simple example if this could also be done

Comment: The `__iter__` method should return a class with a `__next__` method, or a generator. The advantage of using a separate class is it allows you to iterate over a object multiple times without consuming it. For example `iter([])` returns a `list_iterator`, not a list. You can create multiple iterators from the same list